# Selecting second set of 20 row from DataTable

Tags: c#, select, datatable

I have a DataTable I am populating from SQL table with the following example columns

- ID
- Type
- Value

I am populating the DataTable with rows which are of a certain type. I want to select the rows 10 - 20 from my resulting DataTable:

```
Connect conn = new Connect();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn.Connection());

//Creates data
DataTable d = new DataTable();
da.Fill(d);

DataRow[] result = d.Select();
```

In the above code I have omitted the main SQL, and currently I have no select for my DataRow array. I cannot find a way to reference the row numbers.

So for instance I am looking for something like `Select("rownum > X && rownum < Y")`

I have searched here, and a number of other resources to no avail. Any clues would be really handy, or just a simple not possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's always better to select only what you need from the database(f.e. by using the `TOP` clause or a window function like `ROW_NUMBER`) instead of filtering it in memory.

However, you can use `Linq-To-DataSet` and `Enumerable.Skip` + `Enumerable.Take`:

```
var rows = d.AsEnumerable()
    .Skip(9).Take(11);  // select rows 10-20 as desired (so you want 11 rows)
```

If you want a new `DataTable` from the filtered result use `CopyToDataTable`, if you want a `DataRow[]` use `rows.ToArray()`.

Comment: I completely agree. I hate the idea of doing it in memory. I can change it after, just I am hoping to get it working at the moment. I will give this a go. Reading it, I can't see a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I would just do the 'take' and 'skip' command and keep it simple:

```
 d.Select().Skip(10).Take(10);  // skips 10 rows, then selects ten after that.
```

This would be assuming you have the Linq using set (using System.Linq)

Comment: I am using System.Linq. Thanks