# Load data from excel to database without the first row

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like your help as I am totally new in C# and visual Studio. I would like to load an excel table without the first row. Here is my code so far:

```
namespace Calculate_Overtime_Load_in_DB
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ope = new OpenFileDialog();
            ope.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
            if (ope.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(ope.FileName, FileMode.Open);

            IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = false;
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

            DataClasses1DataContext conn = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                {
                    SCE_Overtime addtable= new SCE_Overtime()
                    {
                        Date = Convert.ToString(dr[0]),
                        Name = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                        Work_Shift = Convert.ToString(dr[2]),
                        Approved_Overtime = Convert.ToString(dr[3]),
                        Holiday = Convert.ToString(dr[4]),
                        Final_Overtime = Convert.ToString(dr[5])
                    };

                    conn.SCE_Overtimes.InsertOnSubmit(addtable);
                }
            }

            conn.SubmitChanges();
            excelReader.Close();
            stream.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Table has been laoded!");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I skip the first row of the Excel table?

Comment: *"without the first row"* = `Skip(1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting second set of 20 row from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717644/selecting-second-set-of-20-row-from-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

I've been surfing for a solution and I've found two things:

1. An article that might help you deal with your problem:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47227/reading-data-from-excel-sheet-with-exceldatareader

2. There is another way to read excel files, by using a OLEDB that can convert first row values in column names for your rows (but that can be avoided), so, take a look to this other question and take into account that this guy had a type in his connection string:

[Importing Excel data into C# without first row becoming column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435276/importing-excel-data-into-c-sharp-without-first-row-becoming-column-names)

I hope it helps,

Juan

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if(i > 0){
        //Your Code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's common to ignore the first row because it contains headers.

You have the following code.

```
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = false;
```

Does changing to this...

```
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
```

...remove the need to ignore the first row?